# How to merge instance with a namespace in a declaration file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I create a .d.ts file that represents the following JavaScript API?

- `Loader` is a class which is not exported globally
- `loader` is exported globally, and is an instance of `Loader`
- `loader.Loader` is the `Loader` class itself
- `Loader` has a static method `create`, which creates an instance of `Loader`

So essentially `loader` behaves like a namespace that includes the class `Loader`, but is also a instance of `Loader`. The following doesn't work, because TypeScript won't merge a namespace with a value:

```js
declare namespace loader {
    class Loader {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        load(url: string): any;

        static create(name: string, parent?: Loader): Loader;
    } 
}

// This doesn't work, because a namespace cannot be merged with a value:
declare const loader: loader.Loader;
```

Using this API from JavaScript looks like this:

```js
// Call load() on the default Loader instance
loader.load('/foo/index'); 

// loader.Loader is a class, and loader is an instance of it
if(loader instanceof loader.Loader) {  
    console.log('Yes, loader is a Loader');
}

// Create a new Loader instance
var myLoader = loader.Loader.create('my-loader'); 

// Call load on this Loader instance
myLoader.load('/bar/something'); 

// myLoader is also an instance loader.Loader
if(myLoader instanceof loader.Loader) {  
    console.log('Yes, myLoader is a Loader');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what do you mean when you say "Loader is not exported globally" and "loader is exported globally". A thing can either be exported from module and available for importing in other modules, or not exported - there is no concept of "global export". On the other hand, a thing can be declared to exist in global namespace, like global variables do, to be available in every module without importing anything explicitly.

If you want `loader` with extra `Loader` property to be exported from a module, there is no need to declare a namespace - you can add `Loader` property using intersection type when declaring `loader` instance:

**loader.d.ts**

```
declare class Loader {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    load(url: string): any;

    static create(name: string, parent?: Loader): Loader;
}


declare const loader: Loader & { Loader: typeof Loader };

export {loader};  // Loader is not exported
```

All your examples compile after importing `loader` like this:

```
import {loader} from './loader';


// Call load() on the default Loader instance
loader.load('/foo/index');

// loader.Loader is a class, and loader is an instance of it
if(loader instanceof loader.Loader) {
    console.log('Yes, loader is a Loader');
}

// Create a new Loader instance
var myLoader = loader.Loader.create('my-loader');

// Call load on this Loader instance
myLoader.load('/bar/something');

// myLoader is also an instance loader.Loader
if(myLoader instanceof loader.Loader) {
    console.log('Yes, myLoader is a Loader');
}
```